# Click on a button in a single browser and task should be performed in both opened browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I want to achieve is that I have click here button which will fetch the users name from the DB. Now, I have two browsers opened and are on the same page, so when I click the button on any one browser the data should be shown in both the browser.

Here's the code:

```
<html>

<head>
  <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="sub">click here</button>
  <div id="detail"></div>

  <script>
    function fetch_data() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "select.php",
        method: "POST",
        success: function(data) {
          $('#detail').html(data);
        }
      });
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#sub").click(function() {
        fetch_data();
      });


    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your code is miles away from doing what you want

Comment: then what should I do

Comment: lookup websockets.

Comment: @maru plz send me the link to learn websockets from scratch and to implement it in php

Comment: @Cant I do this using jquery???

Comment: please use a search engine. you asked for what you should do, websockets is a start when you want to do real time or multiple browser syncs.

Answer (score 0):

You going to need a "Realtime Database" to achive what you are looking for. I suggest to use [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/). with firebase data is synced across all clients in realtime, and even remains available when your app goes offline. Instead of typical HTTP requests, the Firebase Realtime Database uses data synchronization—every time data changes, any connected device receives that update within milliseconds. Provide collaborative and immersive experiences without thinking about networking code.

Comment: can I use it to build a chatting app

Comment: @maxtech Yup, you can follow this tutorial : https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-firebase-chat/#0

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to implement websockets, this will enable your site to implement real-time stuff. This used a pub/hub approach under the hood.

If you are using php as backend this may help you: [Socketo](http://socketo.me/)

And for the frontend use something like [jQuery Simple Websockets](http://socketo.me/%20And%20use%20a%20frontend%20library%20like%20this%20http://jbloemendal.github.io/jquery-simple-websocket/) (which works with jQuery)

If you want to simplify the things, the easiest way to do it is using a service like [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) which works for almost anything in real-time (this like chatting apps).

Comment: can I save the datas while using websockets and jquery